# Possible to reference another table as a row in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a Table called Payments, and a couple others called Invoices, Subs, Licenses.

Is it possible to add a reference to these tables in Payments? Something that would generate this

```
result => CREATE TABLE Payments (
      Invoices table,
      Subs table
    )
```

I'm thinking in the same way I can put an object into an array in other languages.

EDIT: Im using MySQL. Basically, I want to map them to Java with one class called Payments and was wondering if I could do this on the db serverside. Otherwise I would have to figure out how to map all of them in the Javaclass. Which Im thinking now might be easier

Comment: Possibly an XY problem here. PostgreSQL supports arrays. Most RDBMS can use a table variable as part of a procedure but not as a column. What is the ultimate goal you're trying to accomplish? Also can you edit the post and add the RDBMS you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, you can have a subquery virtually anywhere you can use an expression.  But it must return a single value.

You can use a "derived table", which is a subquery, as a table-like thing after `FROM` or `JOIN`.

What you typed may be better handled with a `VIEW`:

```
CREATE VIEW Results AS
    SELECT i.*, s.*
        FROM Invoices AS i
        JOIN Subs AS s  ON i.foo = s.foo
```

(where `foo` is the column used for relating those two tables together.)

Comment: Just be really careful with this, as if there is not a direct FK relationship between subs and invoices, you end up with a many-to-many join where you get every invoice for every sub. It cant be for example `sub.customer=invoice.customer` if one customer has both many subs and many invoices.

Comment: "Subs" are ships that sail under the sea.  Or they are submarine-shaped sandwiches.  So I don't have a clue how they are related to Invoices.